# Woocommerce How can i have a price per page text appear in my ink single product pages?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm working in WooCommerce and I want to display a custom field at single product page that contains the result of the attribute "Pages" term, which is always going to be an integer, divided by the  product price.
This way i will have a price per page value appear in ink and toners product pages.

At the moment i'm doing it with a custom field and i manually input the price in the attribute
but I want to do it automatically.
The function i use to display the attribute is this.How do i call the price in the function and where do i do the pages/price?

Thanks for your help.

```
function isa_woo_get_one_pa(){

// Edit below with the title of the attribute you wish to display


global $product;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
 
if ( ! $attributes ) {
    return;
}
  
$out = '';

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    $name = $attribute->get_name();
    if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
      
        
      
        // if this is desired att, get value and label
        if ( $name == 'pa_pages') {
          
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
            // get the taxonomy
            $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
            // get the tax object
            $tax_object = get_taxonomy( $tax );
            // get tax label
            if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
                $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
            } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                $tax_label = ($tax_label);
               
            }
              
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   
                $out .= $tax_label . ': ';
                $out .= $term->name . '<br />';
               
            
            }           
          
        } 
          
    } 
      
  
}
  
echo $out;
```

}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'isa_woo_get_one_pa');

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom field and not an attribute you need to get it with get_post_meta():
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

The hook you use will depend on your theme and where you want to display your calculation, I recommend using guide as start:
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: The values are stired in an attribute, which i call, but how do i divide it with the product price and display the result? The  hook is not a problem,i already use it to display the attribute. Thanks for your answer.